# why can not i get the data from this URL?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

There are some data on this page :

$ scrapy shell "https://partsouq.com/en/catalog/genuine/unit?c=Toyota&ssd=%24HQwdcgcAAwFNa3YjVR92aVB7C10ZDko%24&vid=4463&cid=&uid=2535&q="

and there are numbers on the left hand-side of the page, After clicking on any one of them a table with contents appears like in the attachement, but after making "inspect element" on any item on this table, i get empty set !!

> > response.xpath('//*[@id="gf-result-table"]/tr[2]/td[2]/div').extract()
> >     [ ]

[this shows the tabe and the html code for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR5On.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are giving wrong xpath. correct xpath is

response.xpath('//*[@id="gf-result-table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div')

Comment: why. is data not coming or you have another expection

Answer (score 0):

```
https://partsouq.com/en/search/search?q=0910112012&qty=1
```

this is the url of the attachement, the pop-up window is rendered by JavaScript, you can not do JS things in the scrapy.

And the xpath for the `a` tag is simple:

```
//a[@id]
```

Comment: So how to get the data from JavaScript ?

Comment: @ihathout use xpath find the url and request it